# Send data to a specific solr collection

Tags: collections, solr

I would like to know how to send a data to a specific collection into running Solr instance (actually into running SolrCloud instance).

I've started a SolrCloud instance with a bunch of hand-made collections (using SolrCloud Collections REST API) and hence wanted to send some data to a specific collection in order to easily distinct one sort of data from another. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to do that..

It it possible? If it is than how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection is part of the URL you're using when querying any server, usually located under `http://localhost:8983/solr/<collection name>/`. If you're querying the `products` collection to retrieve all documents, the url would be `http://localhost:8983/solr/products/select?q=*:*`. The same goes for updating a collection, POST your content to `http://localhost:8983/solr/products/update`.

Replace `localhost:8983` with one of your own server host/port combinations.

You can also see further examples in the [Getting Started with Solr Cloud tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Getting+Started+with+SolrCloud).